# Cannot import a groovy class using gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, jvm, dependency-management

I cant seem to get this ([github_link](https://github.com/oehf/ipf/blob/ipf-3.3/platform-camel/ihe/ws/src/test/groovy/org/openehealth/ipf/platform/camel/ihe/ws/StandardTestContainer.groovy)) class imported into my gradle groovy project for testing (Unable to resolve class compile error), Even though the package is coming up in eclipse

[image]

```
import org.openehealth.ipf.platform.camel.ihe.ws.StandardTestContainer
```

I have the testCompile dependency to the containing jar from jcenter ([link](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/org.openehealth.ipf.platform-camel%3Aipf-platform-camel-ihe-ws/3.3.0))

```
    testCompile 'org.openehealth.ipf.platform-camel:ipf-platform-camel-ihe-ws:3.3.0'
```

Comment: Where are you trying to import this class - in `src/main/groovy` or in `src/test/groovy`?

Comment: src/test/groovy @szy

Comment: seems its because the class is compiled into a test-jar; so i need to specify dependency to the test-jar not the main jar

Comment: You wont be able to import this because as you already noticed this class is a part of test classes in the library you added to your project. Those classes are not compiled to a jar you imported. Try importing this class as a source code directly to your project - this might be the easiest way to solve your problem.